# search in a mongod database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Im trying to search in a database, But I don't get any results, and can't find the error, 
I get a empty array in the console, but the database is full of element that includes "a" in this case.

if I try to find all in the database I see all the results, so its something in the $search or $text that breaks the scripts.

All help are really appreciated I've been sitting and tearing my hair for a couple of days!

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var db;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/insights", function(err, database) {
  db = database;
  db.collection("textstore", {}, function(err, coll) {
  if (err != null) {
  db.createCollection("textstore", function(err, result) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
   });
   }
   db.ensureIndex("textstore", {
     document: "text"
   }, function(err, indexname) {
     assert.equal(null, err);
   });
  });
});

app.post("/search", function(req, res) {
  db.collection('textstore').find({"$text": {"$search": 'a'}}).toArray(function(err, items) {
   console.log(items)
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching a MongoDB [text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) is language aware, and the default language is English. Language awareness means that certain words which are very common but usually meaningless are ignored. The word `a` in the English language is such a word. Here is t[he relevant part from the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#supported-languages-and-stop-words):

> MongoDB supports text search for various languages. text indexes drop language-specific stop words (e.g. in English, “the”, “an”, “a”, “and”, etc.) and uses simple language-specific suffix stemming.

Either try searching for something more meaningful or disable the language-awareness during searching by explicitly setting the language to `"none"`.

```
 db.collection('textstore').find({"$text": {"$search": 'a', $language:"none"}})
```

By the way, you can also override the default language when you create the index and even override it on a document and sub-document level. For more information, [check the documentation about specifying languages for text indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/).